# jinja2 variable in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I have an HTML file where I am calling a d3 graph inside a javascript tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/styles/graph.js'> </script>
```

However inside graph.js  I am calling a jinja2 variable:

```
var edaData = {{edaData|safe}};
```

which I need for the graph. I am getting the error:
    `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Expected a property name.`
 How can I solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: What is `edaData`? Is that some Python object? Can you show how you sending that?

Comment: I am sending it via Flask render_template(); It's a list with dictionaries inside [{value: 1, time: 2}, {value 2, time: 3}, {value: 3, time:4}]

Comment: You can't have jinja inside your javascript file. You should call a javascript function in your .js file from the html page with the data as an argument.

Comment: `var edaData = {{edaData|safe}};` is in which method?

Comment: What you can do is, you can pass `edaData` as an argument to that function.